# How can I call jquery ajax inside jquery fancybox plugin?

Tags: api, jquery, plugins, fancybox

```
$('.more').fancybox({
            openEffect  : 'elastic',
            closeEffect : 'elastic',
            $.ajax({
                url: 'results.php',
                type: 'post',
                success:function(data){
                    $('.result').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
```

That's my code, And my firebug has this error:

```
    SyntaxError: missing : after property id
[Break On This Error]   

$.ajax({
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

I came here searching ajax content not loaded inside fancybox. However, the posted owner might have completed this task. I am writing the solution and it might help others.

**After a long search i opened my fancybox js file and searched for oncomplete or callback. there is nothing there. Then I searched for oncancel and seen others functions such as aftershow and beforeshow.**

***Instead of oncomplete I changed it to aftershow and it immediately worked. aftershow is casesensitive and it changes depends upon your fancybox version. check fancybox js for further details***